# Where does HTML DOM start? window? document? document.defaultView?

Tags: javascript, window, document, dom

As the title.

And is there a picture which introduces HTML DOM's construct?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The DOM (**Document** Object Model) begins at the `document` node. It is referred to as the "root node".

Observe the following tree (corresponding `nodeType`s in parentheses):

```
[HTMLDocument](9)
    [DocumentType](10)
    [HTMLHTMLElement](1)
        [HTMLHeadElement](1)
            [HTMLTitleElement](1)
                [Text]Title(3)
        [HTMLBodyElement](1)
```

The tree¹ would be formed from the following markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>Title</title></head></body></html>
```

Note the distinct lack of whitespace. Adding whitespace would add text nodes to the document tree and clearly make it more difficult to simulate.

The `window` object is not part of the DOM. It is a host object implemented as the "[global object](http://es5.github.com/#x15.1)" to complete an ECMAScript implementation. It has its [own standard](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/browsers.html#the-window-object) which is available from the W3C. Whereas the global object is required to complete an ECMAScript implementation, the DOM is not. This is exemplified in the node.js environment.

¹ Certain environments ignore the doctype node. I've observed Opera 5-9 and Safari 3.1 as environments that exhibit this behaviour.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the DOM starts at `document`. BTW, `window` and its properties, methods and events are sometimes referred to as the "BOM", or Browser Object Model.

Comment: Right. The DOM is also language-agnostic. It is not limited to JavaScript nor ECMAScript.

Comment: @MattMcDonald Exactly, as you can observe in PHP's [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) library.

Comment: The Window Object spec draft you link to is rather out of date and appears to be abandoned. It's extracted from Web Apps 1.0 which became part of HTML5, so a better definition is the one in the HTML5 spec here: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/browsers.html#the-window-object

Answer (score -7):

There is no public standard for window, but most browsers support it with Window at the root.
I've found a lot of good stuff at: http://www.w3schools.com (I have no connection with the site).

A simple google search for "dom html" images will get you images. Then...

When all else fails - go to the source: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html

Comment: The window has its own standard. Please see my answer for a link.

Comment: Just in case anyone reading this answer in the future thinks it is correct.. it is not. MattMcDonald's answer is *leaps and bounds* better than this. Also ***NEVER*** listen to w3schools. They do not know what they are talking about and will misguide you.

Comment: I've set Matt McDonald's answer as the accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: Ouch - I should have spent more time on my answer.